# Javascript and templates are in parallel folders how can I serve up both in express?

Tags: javascript, express

### **QUESTION:**

**How do I change my server.js file to allow my three.js script in the index.html to not error `Cannot GET /node_modules/three/three.js`?**

Markup: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>heyyy friends</h1>
    <script src="../node_modules/three/three.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS: server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();



app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('VTEC JUST KICKED IN Y0');
});
```

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder]

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Morningharwood",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server/server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/matthewharwood/MorningHarwood.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/matthewharwood/MorningHarwood/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/matthewharwood/MorningHarwood#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "three": "^0.73.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## server.js

Add the following line under the current line defining static content:

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/../node_modules'));
```

## index.html

Change

```
<script src="../node_modules/three/three.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/node_modules/three/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Mikko.  (This is Morgan)